# manipulate data returned from file

Tags: php

I have a file `$ocsp_resp_file` with the following content:

```
1432599306989.cer.tmp: good
    This Update: May 23 12:54:14 2015 GMT
    Next Update: May 30 12:54:14 2015 GMT
```

I am only interested in the lines starting with "This Update:" and "Next Update:". I would like to retrieve those lines and strip out the spaces and text before the timestamp.

It should end up looking like this:

```
May 23 12:54:14 2015 GMT
May 30 12:54:14 2015 GMT
```

I am using the following code to return each one but not quite how i want it.

```
$search = 'This Update';
        $lines = file($ocsp_resp_file);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
        $line = ltrim($line);
          if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
          //$line = str_replace('This Update: ', '', $line);
            echo $line;
        }
```

The above code returns this:

```
This Update: May 23 12:54:14 2015 GMT
```

I then tried to remove "This Update: " using the following code (now commented out) but it breaks the logic of the code and each line is returned

`$line = str_replace('This Update: ', '', $line);`

Comment: this is marked as duplicate?? the references solution is for a C# language and couldn't see anywhere how it answers my question??

Comment: agreed. looks like @Barmar made a mistake here -ill add an answer link shortly

Comment: The reason for the problem is because you didn't wrap the `if` body in braces. So when you added the `$line = str_replace` line, the `echo` was no longer in the `if`, so every line was echoed. That's why this is a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: That's why it's a bad practice to leave out the braces: when you add another line, and forget to add the braces, you get this problem.

Comment: Thanks Barmer. Adding the `{ }` resolve the issue.

Comment: alternate approach: http://ideone.com/XFxA6v

Comment: nice. thanks for the alternative way.